# period of product markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Consider $Z_n := (X_n,Y_n)$ where $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(Y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ are irreducible markov chains with periods $\lambda$ and $\mu$.
We know that $(Z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Markov Chain then. Work on the following problem:

$\mu$ and $\lambda$ have no common divisor $\iff$ $(Z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is irreducible; further $(Z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ has period $\lambda \mu$ then.

I do not manage. See below:

---

We need to show that $\forall i,j,i',j' \exists n \in \mathbb{N}: P(Z_n = (i',j') | Z_0 = (i,j)) > 0$ $\iff$ $\operatorname{gcd}(\mu,\lambda) = 1$.

$\Rightarrow$ direction:

Consider irreducibilty, then the probabilities are always greater than zero. For an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ especially we have $P(Z_n = (i,j) | Z_0 = (i,j)) > 0$. So we have $n|\mu$ and $n|\lambda$.

But how does this impy that $\lambda$ and $\mu$ have no common divisor?

$\Leftarrow$ direction:

I do not know. It seems that if you have no common divisor you will manage to reach every tuple $(i',j')$ starting from any $(i,j)$ since you can reach every $i'$ from $i$ since X is irreducible and the same goes for the $j$'s. But I do not manage to get this formally written down..

Hints? Is this the right way to go?

Comment: Unfortunately the OP left the site after having asked this 2+ years ago, but... How do we know that if $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(Y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ are irreducible Markov chains and $Z_n := (X_n,Y_n)$ for every $n$ in $\mathbb N$ then $(Z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Markov chain?

Comment: What is the condition for $(X_n,Y_n)$ to be Markov? Will independence of $X_n$ and $Y_n$ do it?

Answer (score 0):

The premise is not correct: consider two independent simple random walks $ \{ X_n : n \geq 0 \} $ and $ \{ Y_n : n \geq 0 \} $. Both have period $ 2 $, i.e., $ \lambda = \mu = 2 $. Then, the joint sequence $ Z_n $ is indeed a Markov chain but not irreducible. For example, the state $ (0,0) \not \leadsto (0,1) $ as starting from states of same parity both random walk states will have same parity, hence they are both even or both odd.  For irreducibility itself, you will need extra conditions such as aperiodicity of original chains.

Answer (score -1):

[Drawing out a simple case, e.g. two circles of length 2 might help visualising the problem (their product becomes a "cross").]

So as OP suggests, for irreducible $Z$ we need $\forall i, i', j, j'$ $\exists n : P_{(i,j)(i',j')}^{(n)}>0$, i.e. there is some $n$ for which the $n$-step transition probability from $(i,j)$ to $(i',j')$ is nonzero (for all pair of vertex tuples). Since $X$ and $Y$ are both irreducible, the real question here is whether it is possible to go $i \rightarrow i'$ (in $X$) and $j \rightarrow j'$ (in $Y$) **in the same number of steps**.

Let the **directed distances**  $i \rightarrow i'$ be ***a* mod** $\bf\lambda$
and  $j \rightarrow j'$ be ***b* mod** $\bf\mu$. This is unique (well-defined) for any pair as both chains are irreducible with periods $\lambda$ and $\mu$.* Then we want $\forall a, b$ $\exists$ $l,m,n$ so that $n=l\lambda +a$ and $n=m\mu+b$, which means that we can get $i\rightarrow i'$ (in $X$) in $a$ steps then we wait there for $l$ full periods while a similar thing happens in $Y$; all these during $n$ steps (for some $n$). This allows to get $(i,j)\rightarrow(i',j')$ in exactly $n$ steps.

WE then turn to number theory. Eliminating $n$ and rearranging, we get $l\lambda-m\mu=b-a$. Having a solution $l,m$ for any $a,b$ corresponds to an irreducible $Z$. This is a linear Diophantine equation in variables $l$ and $m$, and **has a solution** iff gcd$(\lambda,\mu)=1$ (otherwise there is *some* $a-b$ which is not divisible by gcd$(\lambda,\mu)$, whereas the left hand side is). In fact, if there is one solution then there are infinitely many.

To sum up: ($Z$ is irreducible) $\Leftrightarrow$ (equation has a solution) $\Leftrightarrow$ gcd$(\lambda,\mu)=1$. The above also shows that in case of a larger gcd there will be **multiple irreducible classes** which are not communicating with each other.

---

*If there were two paths $i\rightarrow i'$ with different lengths (mod $\lambda$), then the difference would be smaller than $\lambda$, so (if we go back $i'\rightarrow i$ on the same path) there are also two *circles* $i\rightarrow i$ the lengths of which (mod $\lambda$) differ by less than $\lambda$. But this contradicts the definition of period, which requires $\lambda$ to be a divisor of all circle lengths.

Comment: @Did First I thought I can prove $Z$ is a Markov chain, but realised it might not be that easy... But anyway, isn't it a different question? There is probably some $X$ & $Y$ which give a valid $Z$, and my answer can still hold for those